# measure CPU usage of the JVM : java code

Tags: java, performance, cross-platform, jmx, cpu-usage

Is there a way to measure CPU usage of the JVM (once a java application is started) cross platform (windows + unix + mac)?
I have used Jconsole but what I need is a java code that does this, and not a tool through which I can monitor CPU utilization.
I have tried out

```
ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getSystemLoadAverage()
```

using JMX, but it doesn't help since what I need is the specific CPU usage by the JVM (say when I start a server), not the system load average.

Answer (score 9):

You should have a look at the [ThreadMXBean.getThreadCPUTime()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadCpuTime%28long%29) method from the Thread MBean.

> **Thread CPU time**
>
> A Java virtual machine
> implementation may support measuring
> the CPU time for the current thread,
> for any thread, or for no threads.

There is also the JTop sample application that's part of the JDK `jdk\demo\management\JTop\src\JTop.java` or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ExampleofusingthejavalangmanagementAPItosortthreadsbyCPUusage.htm). Have a look at:

```
/**
 * Get the thread list with CPU consumption and the ThreadInfo for each thread
 * sorted by the CPU time.
 */
private List<Map.Entry<Long, ThreadInfo>> getThreadList()
```

Comment: hi, is there a way to get cpu usage (in percentage) for the JVM using the ThreadMXBean.getCurrentCPUTime() method mentioed please?

Comment: You have to calculate the sum of the CPU times of all threads to get the total CPU time. I think the sum could be off a bit because you cannot query for all threads' CPU times atomically.

Answer (score 2):

At any given instant, a thread is either running (100% of core) or not (0%).
There is no in-between.
What you need is a short-term series of snapshots of the thread's running state, and average it over those.

Comment: Can you detail out a bit more? Won't you have to account for threads that get blocked or are in timed_waiting state? I have seen timed_waiting threads taking up cpu cycles at times. My requirement is to trigger the jvm to take more thread dumps when the cpu usage crosses a threshold value, so that we could investigate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://knight76.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/how-to-get-java-cpu-usage-jvm-instance.html)

```
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = 
         (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    int availableProcessors = operatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors();
    long prevUpTime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime();
    long prevProcessCpuTime = operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime();
    double cpuUsage;
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } 
    catch (Exception ignored) { }

    operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    long upTime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime();
    long processCpuTime = operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime();
    long elapsedCpu = processCpuTime - prevProcessCpuTime;
    long elapsedTime = upTime - prevUpTime;

    cpuUsage = Math.min(99F, elapsedCpu / (elapsedTime * 10000F * availableProcessors));
    System.out.println("Java CPU: " + cpuUsage);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to give an accurate value. Comparing it with what I see in jconsole, the calculation is 65% when the cpu usage is already 99% on jconsole. Any java alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Java itself not providing this feature. There are couple of opensource APIs available to measure CPU Usage. 
I recommend [Sigar API](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar). Apart from CPU usage, you can get lot more other features like memory usage, System uptime etc.

Comment: This is not correct since Java 1.5, when ThreadMXBean.getCurrentCPUTime() was introduced, see @thomas-jung's answer. But Sigar does have some interesting functionality.

Comment: SIGAR cantake down your JVM also and crash everything. Even if it is intermittent, i don't think you can afford that in production .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon/) or similar libraries could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use https://github.com/mvysny/webmon . You just add the webmon-analyzer jar to your project and you'll start the sampler and TCP/IP server. The sampler will poll JMX API and will keep the stats for awhile, you can then simply `telnet localhost 5455` to get a text dump of those stats. Awesome for production. Disclaimer: I'm the author, and the project is old-ish.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically querying for CPU usage is impossible using pure Java. There is simply no API for this. A suggested alternative might use `Runtime.exec()` to determine the JVM's process ID (PID), call an external, platform-specific command like ps, and parse its output for the PID of interest.

[See this link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-11/01-qa-1108-cpu.html)

Comment: This is not correct since Java 1.5, when  ThreadMXBean.getCurrentCPUTime() was introduced, see @Thomas-jung's answer. Also, the linked article is from 2002.